# Integration testing a small Java server application

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, testing, integration-testing

I want to write some integration tests for a small server application I have written but I'm not sure what to start with. I have the following server code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class KKMultiServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.err.println("Usage: java KKMultiServer <port number>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        boolean listening = true;

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber)) { 
            while (listening) {
                new KKMultiServerThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port " + portNumber);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

My other class:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class KKMultiServerThread extends Thread {
    private Socket socket = null;

    public KKMultiServerThread(Socket socket) {
        super("KKMultiServerThread");
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {

        try (
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
            String inputLine, outputLine;
            KnockKnockProtocol kkp = new KnockKnockProtocol();
            outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
            out.println(outputLine);

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
                out.println(outputLine);
                if (outputLine.equals("Bye"))
                    break;
            }
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

(Taken from [Oracle's page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html#later))

How would I go about writing integration tests for code like this? I have no idea where to start. The only integration testing I have done in the past has been with Selenium and web applications, never a multi-threaded socket server application like this.

Answer (score 0):

Set your socket to listen to port 80 and then you can use the tools you are used to for integration testing (selenium etc..). Your url will be "http://localhost"

Answer (score 0):

Its more of what scenario would you test rather than how to test. For e.g: if its simple request reply testing then you can start the server and client as setUp() and then in your tests try to pass different requests from client session to server process and check its reply. If the server replies in stream of messages then collect that stream and verify order of messages, message content (or response), or what type of object did server send. Apart from that you can also have session lifecycle test for e.g: what would a general client scenario include in a single session. You can also test how does server process responds when there are multiple clients requesting to same server. Normal test frameworks like JUnit or TestNG can be used in that case. If this involves a lot more than that you can have a look at Citrus Framework as well